# form submit jQuery mobile

Tags: coldfusion, jquery-mobile

I've gotten it into my head that mobile applications don't like form submits the same way html does, so I thought I'd better have a sanity check on Stackoverflow.

For example, instead of having <input type="submit"...>, it looks like I should now use <a data-role="button"...>

Q: Can I continue to use <input type="submit"...> for mobile applications?

The reason why I ask is because the action page has some logic, such as:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form,"Save")>
```

Comment: wondering just the same thing and have not found a nice implementation/tutorial with programmatically submitting a JQM form.

Comment: Interesting. Here is the docs on Form submission: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/forms/forms-sample.html and button type docs are here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html to my understanding you look to be fine using input type submit. Also there are some tidbits in the release notes as well: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/09/29/jquery-mobile-1-0rc1-released/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile, at least as of this writing, by default submits forms via AJAX using the method specified on the form being submitted.  POST submissions will still be posted to the server in the background, so ColdFusion will still see the form variables that are passed in as usual.  When a response is generated, jQuery Mobile will take the response and transition the view over to whatever HTML was returned.  In my own testing you can continue to use a normal submit button as well.  If you want a standard submission rather than an AJAX submission, add `data-ajax="false"` to the form tag.

Comment: Justin, what do you mean by "transition the view over whatever HTML was returned"?

Comment: jQuery Mobile does nearly all of its display inside of a single "browser window" (e.g. a single DOM).  When it gets new HTML content back from a request it will create a new "page" object on the DOM and then transition (slide, fade, fold, or whatever type of transition you have enabled) it into the viewing area over top of whatever the previously displayed "page" was.  Remember, this is all happening within the context of a single traditional "page" (DOM hierarchy).  Once you "get" that concept of how it handles "pages" a lot of the jQuery mobile stuff will suddenly make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programatically submit a form, set the `data-ajax` attribute for the form to `false` and then set an event handler for the `submit` event for the form:

```
<form data-ajax=false></form>

$(function () {
    $('form').bind('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('path/to/server.file', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            alert('Server Response: ' + data);
        });
    });
});
```